# XSLT - Get unique Keys and merge data in one step

Tags: xml, xslt, distinct

I have a XML File where I have several Fields for years, Year1, Year2, Year3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<data>
 <row>
<field fieldno="Name">Hello</field>
<field fieldno="Year1">2014</field>
<field fieldno="Year2">2015</field>
<field fieldno="Year3">2016</field>

</row>
 <row>
<field fieldno="Name">NotWelcome</field>
<field fieldno="Year1">2016</field>
<field fieldno="Year2">2017</field>
<field fieldno="Year3">2018</field>
</row>
<row>
<field fieldno="Name">Welcome</field>
<field fieldno="Year1">2014</field>
<field fieldno="Year2">2015</field>
<field fieldno="Year3">2016</field>
</row>
<row>
<field fieldno="Name">Goodbye</field>
<field fieldno="Year1">2015</field>
<field fieldno="Year2">2016</field>
<field fieldno="Year3">2017</field>
 </row>
</data>
```

I want to get all appearing years in the XML file, but only once, so for my file I need:

2014 2015 2016 2017 2018

I read some stuff about muenchian grouping and got the correct result for one field by this transformation:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:key name="unique-year" match="row" use="field[@fieldno='Year1']" />
      <xsl:key name="unique-year2" match="row" use="field[@fieldno='Year2']" />
      <xsl:key name="unique-year3" match="row" use="field[@fieldno='Year3']" />

      <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('unique-year', field[@fieldno='Year1'])[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:sort select="field[@fieldno='Year1']" />
          <xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='Year1']" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I dont really know how to get the single results merged, so I get one overall result.

How can I manage this?

In addition, I do not understand the line, I just adopted it for my requirements but I dont know whats going on here:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('unique-year', field[@fieldno='7015'])[1]) = 1]">
```

Do one of you guys have an explanation for me whats happening here?

Thanks and kind regards,

Alex

Comment: To understand Muenchian grouping, read the definitive article:http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html -- Your question is difficult to understand, because your stylesheet does not fit the XML example.

Comment: Also, you need to provide us with expected output.

Comment: Oh, Im very sorry, I revised the stylesheet.

Comment: The output is currently: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>201420152016 -- > I would be happy if I get 20142015201620172018 instead (ALL Years). The particular issue with my question is, that I want to group over several fields.

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="field" match="field" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:for-each select="row/field[@fieldno='Year1' or @fieldno='Year2' or @fieldno='Year3'][count(. | key('field', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your XML example, will return:

```
2014 2015 2016 2017 2018
```

Not sure what your real situation is, but in this case the expression:

```
row/field[@fieldno='Year1' or @fieldno='Year2' or @fieldno='Year3']
```

could be simplified to:

```
row/field[@fieldno!='Name']
```

---

### Edit:

To count the distinct values, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(row/field[@fieldno='Year1' or @fieldno='Year2' or @fieldno='Year3'][count(. | key('field', .)[1]) = 1])" />
```

within the same template (but outside the `<xsl:for-each>` element).

Comment: This runs super smooth, thank you so much. Is there a possibility to get the amount of records into a variable, so in our case 5?

Comment: I have tried several things in the meantime this one looks to me to deliver the correct result:            <xsl:variable name="count" select="last()"/> Can someone please confirm that this approach is correct?

Comment: <xsl:variable name="Columns_Part3" select="count(row/field[(@tableshort = 'Y1' and @fieldno='7015') or (@tableshort = 'Y1' and @fieldno='7016') or (@tableshort = 'Y1' and @fieldno='7017')][count(. | key('field', .)[1]) = 1])"/>
 this one works.. but its really difficult for me to understand

Comment: @user3898488 See the edit to my post. -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable